# Why is one nested while loop faster than the other nested while loop?

Tags: java, algorithm

So I was in class writing a nested while loop to calculate the value of z. I need to output both z and time it takes to get it.

Here is the result

```
public class TimeWhile {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 100000;
    int z = 1;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int x = 0;
    while (x <= n) {
        int y = 0;
        while (y <= n) {
            z = x * y;
            y++;
        }
        x++;
    }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsed = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("The time is " + elapsed);
    System.out.println("The number is " + z);

}

}
```

[image]

Second while loop

```
public class TimeWhile {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 100000;
    int z = 1;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    while (x <= n) {
        while (y <= n) {
            z = x * y;
            x++;
            y++;    
        }
    }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsed = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("The time is " + elapsed);
    System.out.println("The number is " + z);

}

}
```

[image]

Why does the second run much faster? The output "z" is the same.

Comment: Because you never reset `y` in the latter, so after the first iteration of the outer `while`, the inner `while` loop is *never* executed. This means that the first algorithm has run time *O(n^2)*, whereas the latter has *O(n)*.

Comment: Good time to learn to use a debugger and then use it to step through your code. An even better skill is to practice walking through your code mentally as if *you* were the computer/JVM, asking yourself what the code is doing at each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are many things that are wrong with this code.

First of all there is no need to calculate `z = x * y` inside the loop as each but the last iteration overwrites the value. So your code is effectively the same as:

```
heatTheUniverseForSomeTime();
int z = n*n;
```

It means that the fact that the output of `z` is the same actually means almost nothing about how the loops work.

Secondly `int` is not sufficiently large type to hold the value of `100000*100000`. That's why you have `1410065408` instead of more expected `10000000000`. `long` would help (but beware you should cast at least one argument to `long` on the right as well!). If you need even bigger values, consider [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Third point is that your first example could be re-written in a much more usual and thus understandable form by using the `for` loop as in:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= n; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y <= n; y++) {
        z = x * y;
    }
}
```

This code clearly needs to run `n*n` iterations in total.

Also I believe that now point #1 becomes even more clear.

Finally your second code is not equivalent to this in 2 different aspects:

- as was pointed out you never reset the `y` so after the first time the inner run loop runs it never runs again
- moreover since you do `x++;` in the inner loop as well, it means it always holds that `x == y`, so the outer loop never runs after the first iteration as well.

You second code is effectively the same as

```
for(int x = 0, y = 0; y <= n && x <= n; x++, y++) {
    z = x * y;
}
```

This code clearly needs to run only `n` times instead of `n*n` which is much much faster.

Answer (score 2):

In the first loop the value of `y` is always assigned to `zero` on every `iteration`, making it take more time and steps to reach `n` while in the second loop, `y` isn't resetted to `zero` thus it reaches n faster and in less steps.

**loop1**

```
while (x <= n) {
        int y = 0;
```

**loop2**

```
 while (x <= n) {
        while (y <= n) {
            z = x * y;
            x++;
            y++;    
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The second runs much faster because you increment x in the nested while loop, rather than in the outer while loop. The nested while loop runs many more times than the outer loop because it will keep repeating until the outer loop's condition is false. If you put x in the nested loop, it will repeat more times successively, making the outer loop's condition false quicker.